# How to check if an AJAX response has HTML contents in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, response

I have a page with one form and two possible responses in the event of a successful AJAX call, one of which only returns a status code.

What I need to do is check the `response` object in my success callback for any HTML contents so that I can display them on my page.

I already know that I can access `response` in my callback by adding it as a parameter, like so:

`function success(response) {  }`

The only thing I can't figure out is how to check if that object has any HTML contents. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you know the exact response on success, if so - you could check for success instead, and then assume html/failure if it is not.

Comment: Well, if one only returns a status code, `if(response.indexOf('<') > -1)` because status codes don't have `<` but html does.

Comment: It's not a best practice at all...but the way you're sending it back isn't either. I'd send back `echo json_encode(array('success' => true, 'html' => '<html stuff>'))` when successful, otherwise, `echo json_encode(array('success' => false))` when not successful and check if `resonse.success !== false`

Comment: Ok. And you do not know enough about the status code without html to be able to recognise that one? (or just do as Ohgodwhy says). And yes, you would be cleaner to make the API always return json, with the html  in the json response if needed.

Comment: Sorry for the PHP, poor assumption on my part. Looks like Andre has it in the answer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You probably want to look at the response headers for an HTML MIME type. [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) will pass a [`jqXHR`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) object back into your `success` callback, which you can then call [`.getResponseHeader()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FXMLHttpRequest#getResponseHeader()) on:

```
function success( response, status, jqXHR ) {
    if( jqXHR.getResponseHeader('content-type').indexOf('text/html') >= 0 ) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I've edited my answer to check for the presence of `text/html` with `indexOf()` as the value for that header will likely include additional information: e.g., `text/html; charset=utf-8`