# How to return partial view or Json result based on condition?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have following code in the controller, here I want to return Partial View or Json Result to jquery. My problem is when this controller is hit jquery blocks the UI with some progress bar and waiting for response until it return. But when ModelState is false it return partial view which bypass jquery unblock UI. So this makes UI block forever.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Form form)
{
  ...
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
     return PartialView("EditPartial", model);
  }  

   return Json(new
   {
      Success = true,
      Id = ID
    });
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You need to change your JavaScript code to handle getting back either HTML or a JSON result and behave appropriately. The problem isn't really in your controller, it's in your JavaScript.

Comment: Check the response content type. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17864944/how-to-check-if-an-ajax-response-has-html-contents-in-jquery) post. This should help you identify what has to be done with the response.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller method is behaving properly. You just need to modify your ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '<your url>',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) { 
        // You have the json result.
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
        // You have the partial view 
    }
});
```

An empty response is also is considered to be a failed json parse. Your controller method should either return a response of null or {} instead.

See the below url for more details of `dataType` and `error`

```
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
```