# How to detect if request is AJAX from JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a messaging system for which I do infinite scroll using `jQuery.load`. The problem is that the way I set it up, when the response of `jQuery.load` returns, all JS from the page is ran once again. This is fine, but I want to disable a particular JS block only if the request is an AJAX (`jQuery.load`).

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
if(!request_is_ajax){
    run_some_code();
}
else{
    // do nothing
}
```

Basically the code should run on the main pageload, but not on subsequent calls. I can detect this server-side, but that would be the last resort for me.

Comment: maybe you can set a global js variable to false once you loaded the code you want, and then check if it's true when the code executes again.

Comment: @Bobby5193 if you would kindly post the comment as an answer, I'd be glad to accept it. Worked great. No idea why I didn't think of that.

Comment: ok, I did that just now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a global js variable to false once you loaded the code you want, and then check if it's true when the code executes again.
I don't think a code snippet is really necessary here.

Answer (score 1):

For the subsequent call (ie ajax call after page load) append something like  ?ajax or &ajax and check the same on server side to know whether the request is an Ajax request or not.

```
// a server side php code sample
   $request_is_ajax= @$_GET['ajax']?true:false;
   if(!$request_is_ajax){
        run_some_code();
    }
    else{
        // do nothing
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `jQuery`, you can check `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']`, which will be set to `XMLHttpRequest.` This is the most reliable method when using `jQuery` because the `XMLHttpRequest` is JavaScript object that makes the request. It's poorly named now, though, because you can have it send whatever you want.

**Example code:**

```
/* decide what the content should be up here .... */
$content = get_content(); //generic function;

/* AJAX check  */
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    /* special ajax here */
    die($content);
}

/* not ajax, do more.... */
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check in the Responseheader, because $.ajax will send an jqXHR(jQueryXMLHttpRequest).

The statement would be something like this:

```
    if( jqXHR.getResponseHeader('content-type').indexOf('text/html') >= 0 ) {
    ...
    }
```

For further information you can look up [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17864944/how-to-check-if-an-ajax-response-has-html-contents-in-jquery)